# Spring security custom login page

Tags: spring, spring-security, login-page

Can anybody please help me to get how can i add more field in custom login jsp file ? The default is "j_username" and "j_password". What if i want to add more field i.e  and want to get it in my `CustomAuthenticationProvider` class which extends `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`. If there is any resource or link out there please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the [official FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-extra-login-fields):

> #### 1.1.  I need to login in with more information than just the username. How do I add support for extra login fields (e.g. a company name)?
>
> This question comes up repeatedly in the Spring Security forum so you will find more information there by searching the archives (or through google).
>
> The submitted login information is processed by an instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. You will need to customize this class to handle the extra data field(s). One option is to use your own customized authentication token class (rather than the standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`), another is simply to concatenate the extra fields with the username (for example, using a "`:`" as the separator) and pass them in the username property of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.
>
> You will also need to customize the actual authentication process. If you are using a custom authentication token class, for example, you will have to write an `AuthenticationProvider` to handle it (or extend the standard `DaoAuthenticationProvider`). If you have concatenated the fields, you can implement your own `UserDetailsService` which splits them up and loads the appropriate user data for authentication.