# Spring - Adding element(checkbox) to Spring login page (with Spring-security)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

In my web application I am using Spring login form (with Spring-security). By default the login form has the fields j_username and j_password. I need to add one more element(checkbox for Terms&Conditions). The current code doesn't have LoginForm as well as LoginController since Spring is internally handling it.
Can anyone please tell how to handle/override this?

I have seen this link [Spring security custom login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571383/spring-security-custom-login-page)
But I need to add the new element in LoginForm (which is not existing currently) - where I need to add this new element(in Form - .java file)
Also should I write a new controller (LoginController) or can I use any existing filter as given here? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#filter-stack

Comment: Maybe is useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652997

Comment: you can use a custom login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the user just have to check the box in order to procede, or does it bind to a backing model object.

If it's the former, I'd just handle it through javascript.  If the latter, the easiest way would probably be implementing an Authentication Filter, this area of the documentation might help:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-filter